# How to remove the caption and the figure x in the figure but to add the caption in the list of figures?

Tags: table-of-contents, captions

I would like to remove figure 1 from the caption under my figure but to have it in my list of figures. Is it possible?

With `\caption[Entry for the List of Figures (LoF)]{}\label{fig:without}` I can have the caption in my list of figures but I still have  "Figure 1" under my figure and I would like to remove that.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. It's not very clear why the caption shouldn't appear below the figure.

Comment: Is it good to have a figure with list entry _and_ without caption and number in the text? Anyway, you can do `\refstepcounter{figure}\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline{\thefigure}{Caption}}` instead of `\caption`. It increments the `figure` counter and adds a line to `\listoffigures`. (`\addcontentsline{lof}{figure}{\numberline{}{Caption}}` without the number and without increasing the `figure` counter.)

Comment: Thank you. What exactly is the \numberline and \thefigure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the macro `\addcontentsline` to add a list entry to the List of Figures (or others).

It takes three arguments:

1. the filename-extension of the list. (`toc` for Table of Contents, `lof` for Lists of Figures, `lot` for List of Tables, …)
2. the structure level

   - `toc`: `part`, `chapter`, `section`, …
   - `lof`: `figure`
   - `lot`: `table`
3. the entry itself. Mostly it is preceeded by `\protect\numberline{…}` whose argument is the number for the entry and it aligns the following text.

My code provides two three commands:

- `\nocaption` that adds only an caption text to the list,
- `\nocaptionbutnumber` that adds additionally a number to the entry (that is incremented before, and
- `\nocaptionwithweirdalignment` that doesn't use `\numberline` and therefore its entry text is aligned to the left (I wouldn't use it).

#### Minor Update

I've updated the answer so that the `\addcontentsline` macro doesn't have hard-coded first and second parameter. The commands should work now in `table` and other environment that define `\@captype` and the proper extension macro `\ext@<\@captype>`.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\nocaption}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{\csname ext@\@captype\endcsname}{\@captype}{\protect\numberline{}#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\nocaptionbutnumber}[1]{%
    \refstepcounter{figure}%
    \addcontentsline{\csname ext@\@captype\endcsname}{\@captype}{\protect\numberline{\csname the\@captype\endcsname}#1}%%
}
\newcommand*{\nocaptionwithweirdalignment}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{\csname ext@\@captype\endcsname}{\@captype}{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}[!ht]
F1
\nocaption{Caption 1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
F2
\nocaptionbutnumber{Caption 2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
F3
\nocaptionbutnumber{Caption 3}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
F4
\nocaptionwithweirdalignment{Caption 4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]